# Best way to split "a{b}c{d}"

Tags: java, split

I'm struggling other than brute force method to split

```
String str = "a{b}c{d}"
```

into

```
String[] arr;
arr[0] = "a"
arr[1] = "{b}"
arr[2] = "c"
arr[3] = "{d}"
```

Wondering if there's a more efficient way other out there than using indexOf and subString

Comment: `"a {b} c {d}".split(" ");`?

Comment: `"a {b} c {d}".split("\\s+")`

Comment: This needs to be reopened since the question has changed. There are no spaces anymore

Comment: Use could create a regex using java.util.regex.Pattern for a better performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your current edit it looks like you want to split on place which is either

- directly before `{`
- directly after `}`

In that case you can use `split` method which supports regex (regular expression). Regex provides [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms like

- `(?=subregex)` to see if we are directly *before* something which can be matched by `subregex`
- `(?<=subregex)` to see if we are directly *after* something which can be matched by `subregex`

Also `{` and `}` are considered regex metacharacters (we can use them like `{m,n}` to describe amount of repetitions like `a{1,3}` can match `a`, `aa`, `aaa` but not `aaaa` or more) so to make it normal literal we need to escape it like `\{` and `\}`

Last thing you need is `OR` operator which is represented as `|`.

So your code can look like:

```
String str = "a{b}c{d}";
String[] arr = str.split("(?=\\{)|(?<=\\})"); // split at places before "{" OR after "}"
for (String s : arr){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
a
{b}
c
{d}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/FdUbKs

Answer (score 1):

just use the String.split() method [(documentation)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
arr = str.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`String.split(String delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method :

```
String str = "a {b} c {d}";
String[] arr = str.split(" ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));  //  [a, {b], c, {d}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)...

`String[] arr = str.split(" ");`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's as efficient as the previous regex solutions; I'm putting a single white space before { and after } then splitting string by " ":

```
    String str = "a{b}c{d}";
    String[] split = str.replace("{"," {").replace("}","} ").split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Desired output:

```
    [a, {b}, c, {d}]
```